# What is the policy on occasionally answering questions anonymously?

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-accounts

I was in a situation earlier where a colleague had a problem I knew the answer to. Because of office-political reasons I couldn't help (this isn't your project etc) so I hinted that he should post the question on Stack Overflow, and then created a temporary account and answered anonymously, and solved his issue in the process.

Is this breaking any terms and conditions? Also has the ability to post comments/questions incognito as it were been considered by the Stack Overflow team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is a good one (in line with what we consider good for the site), and the answer is as well, there is no real problem I'd say. As long as you don't end up being a bit too friendly when it comes to voting of course. And having multiple accounts is no problem either. Once again, if you keep the voting honest.

Comment: The safest bet to prevent accidental voting fraud is to not vote from the alter-ego at all.

Comment: @JanDvorak Dammit, I was just about to vote.